# Is there an easy way I can automaticaly change the href link for an image on a certain website?

Tags: google-chrome, html

As an example, is there anything that would permanently change the link of the superuser logo from superuser.com to stackexchange.com

[example mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnSiw.png)

Is there any chrome extension or other method that could be used to achieve this?

Comment: you could try [this method](https://blog.lateral.io/2016/04/create-chrome-extension-modify-websites-html-css/)

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @DavidPostill Well the particular use I had in mind is for Facebook, because I have a interest list that only shows posts from a couple of close friends that I actually care about. To access it, I have to scroll down to the option on the navigation menu, and often find myself clicking the fb logo habitually and ending back on the main news feed. So yeah, as pathetic and unimportant as it is I'd rather not have the  option to be distracted by the infinite scroll of facebook posts.

Comment: @theDistantStar Thanks, being relatively non-technical (although trying to learn web development as a side hobby) still hoping there is a simpler "end user" solution, but will give it a try if nothing comes up.